# Can't extend session expiry

Tags: php, session, cookies, safari

I am currently building a website where basket data etc is being stored in session variables. The issue is that with default settings the session expires at the end of the session.

I have tried a range of suggestions as to how to modify the session expiry date, and on using `$params = session_get_cookie_params(); var_dump($params);` I can see that the session expiration has changed to what I set.

My issue using the web inspector on Safari 8.0.8, the session cookie still says to expire at the end of the session. I have also tried manually updating the cookie using the `setcookie()` command.

Currently I'm running on a localhost, but with a view to initially deploy on a shared web server.

Is this expected? A problem with safari? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Session timeout is a notion that has to be implemented in code if you want strict guarantees; that's *the only way* you can be absolutely certain that no session ever will survive after X minutes of inactivity.

If relaxing this requirement a little is acceptable and you are fine with placing a *lower bound* instead of a strict limit to the duration, you can do so easily and without writing custom logic.

### Convenience in relaxed environments: how and why

**If** your sessions are implemented with cookies (which they probably are), and **if** the clients are not malicious, you can set an upper bound on the session duration by tweaking certain parameters. If you are using PHP's default session handling with cookies, setting [`session.gc_maxlifetime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime) along with [`session_set_cookie_params`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) should work for you like this:

```
// server should keep session data for AT LEAST 1 hour
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 3600);

// each client should remember their session id for EXACTLY 1 hour
session_set_cookie_params(3600);

session_start(); // ready to go!
```

This works by configuring the server to keep session data around for at least one hour of inactivity and instructing your clients that they should "forget" their session id after the same time span. **Both of these steps are required to achieve the expected result.**

- If you don't tell the clients to forget their session id after an hour (or if the clients are malicious and choose to ignore your instructions) they will keep using the same session id and its effective duration will be non-deterministic. That is because sessions whose lifetime has expired on the server side are not garbage-collected immediately but only [whenever the session GC kicks in](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-divisor).

  GC is a potentially expensive process, so typically the probability is rather small or even zero (a website getting huge numbers of hits will probably forgo probabilistic GC entirely and schedule it to happen in the background every X minutes). In both cases (assuming non-cooperating clients) the lower bound for effective session lifetimes will be `session.gc_maxlifetime`, but the upper bound will be unpredictable.
- If you don't set `session.gc_maxlifetime` to the same time span then the server might discard idle session data earlier than that; in this case, a client that still remembers their session id will present it but the server will find no data associated with that session, effectively behaving as if the session had just started.

### Certainty in critical environments

You can make things completely controllable by using custom logic to also place an *upper bound* on session inactivity; together with the lower bound from above this results in a strict setting.

Do this by saving the upper bound together with the rest of the session data:

```
session_start(); // ready to go!

$now = time();
if (isset($_SESSION['discard_after']) && $now > $_SESSION['discard_after']) {
    // this session has worn out its welcome; kill it and start a brand new one
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    session_start();
}

// either new or old, it should live at most for another hour
$_SESSION['discard_after'] = $now + 3600;
```

### Session id persistence

So far we have not been concerned at all with the exact values of each session id, only with the requirement that the data should exist as long as we need them to. Be aware that in the (unlikely) case that session ids matter to you, care must be taken to regenerate them with `session_regenerate_id` when required.

Comment: Im pretty sure this is off another post I read on this issue. As I have already posted, these methods are not working for the cookie in safari